# Weird created_at behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, time, utc

I've set `config.time_zone = 'UTC'` in `environment.rb`, and yet still I get some weird behavior with Rails' built-in datetime fields:

```
>> Time.now
=> Sun Jun 21 17:05:59 -0700 2009
>> Feedback.create(:body => "testing")
=> #<Feedback id: 23, body: "testing", email_address: nil, name: nil, created_at: "2009-06-22 00:06:09", updated_at: "2009-06-22 00:06:09">
>> Time.parse(Feedback.last.created_at.to_s)
=> Mon Jun 22 00:06:09 UTC 2009
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it's properly setting the timezone in the ActiveRecord object, so I don't think you need to worry too much. If you want to force your timestamp from Rails to use UTC, you can use [`Time.utc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000251).

```
Time.now.utc
=> Mon Jun 22 00:54:21 UTC 2009
```